# Enable VX-T on Dell Precision Tower 3620

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I am getting an error in Virtual Box: "Failed to open session for the virtual machine" "VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)"

My machine is a Dell Precision Tower 3620. When enter the bios by pressing F2 and go to the Intel Virtualization screen is is ticket on.

What do I need to do to get this working?

My host OS is Windows 10 Enterprise.

This happened after I installed Docker and uninstalled it again.

[image: Virtual Box error message]

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by turning off Hyper-V in Windows 10 Features panel.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help with `VERR_VMX_NO_VMX` and `VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT` errors too
https://superuser.com/a/1415967/155706